Emacs asks for 'install package all?' when typing a comment in C/C++ mode
I am using Emacs 29.4 (built from source) and would like to customize it for C/C++ programming. I followed this tutorial (https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/tutorials/CPP-guide/) and all the features (e.g., code completion, code navigation, etc...) work fine.
However, when I insert a comment like:
/* this is a comment */ 

Emacs prompts 'Install package all? (yes or no)' as soon as I type three letters inside the comment (i.e., /* thi). The problem occurs only when I edit a file from a project built with CMake. If I edit a new .c file not related to a project, comments work fine.
This is my init.el
;; Display line numbers
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)

;; Add packages
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

;; C/C++ Settings
(setq package-selected-packages '(lsp-mode yasnippet lsp-treemacs helm-lsp
    projectile hydra flycheck company avy which-key helm-xref dap-mode))

(when (cl-find-if-not #'package-installed-p package-selected-packages)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (mapc #'package-install package-selected-packages))

;; sample `helm' configuration use https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/ for details
(helm-mode)
(require 'helm-xref)
(define-key global-map [remap find-file] #'helm-find-files)
(define-key global-map [remap execute-extended-command] #'helm-M-x)
(define-key global-map [remap switch-to-buffer] #'helm-mini)

(which-key-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'lsp)

(setq gc-cons-threshold (* 100 1024 1024)
      read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)
      treemacs-space-between-root-nodes nil
      company-idle-delay 0.2
      company-minimum-prefix-length 3
      lsp-idle-delay 0.1)  ;; clangd is fast

(with-eval-after-load 'lsp-mode
  (add-hook 'lsp-mode-hook #'lsp-enable-which-key-integration)
  (require 'dap-cpptools)
  (yas-global-mode))

The problem seems related to:
(which-key-mode)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'lsp)

If I comment out these lines, the problem disappears but, of course, I loose all the C/C++ features.

"and all the features work fine" Have you checked they don't interfere?

I am not sure how to systematically check that they do not interfere. I have tested on a large project auto completion and code navigation (i.e., find function definition and declaration) features and they work as expected.
